# Need to Show Places on Map from Database based on Longitude And Latitude

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

In my Api , I have to show several places in the map whose Longitude And Latitude are fetched from database , i am working in php , How can this will be done??

Comment: I had faced some issue in application and i have posted same here , But i dont know why This question has been marked as Closed or Not Real , Would u guys (@Marcelo, Jocelyn, webarto, tereško, PeeHaa) please tell me why you marked is as Closed , instead to give any solution like others??

Comment: @Jocelyn....................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the reference. It may help you https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

Comment: thank you @ROhit .. i have used your refernce and its works for me same as i want..:)

Answer (score 4):

The  [**Google tutorial**](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) is excellent. But as it uses the deprecated  mysql_ extensions I have modified it to use [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). See map [**HERE**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/markerMap.php)

```
<?php
require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
     $stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1');  
     // setting the fetch mode  
     $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     header("Content-type: text/xml");
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {  
        // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
    }
echo $dom->saveXML();
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error .". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", phpsqlajax_genxml.php , ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 
?>
```

You can view the XML generated [**HERE**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/mapPDO.php)

**phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php**

```
<?
$username="username";
$password="password";
$database="username-databaseName";
?>
```

Comment: Just what i was looking for. @david strachan

Comment: where is phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php file @david strachan

Comment: @VipulK Added **phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php** to Answer. Change to suit your database connection parameters.