# Google Map: Distance of markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I pull Lat/Long from a SQL database and map that data as markers and it's been working fine. Now I need to calculate the length (sum of the distance between each marker) of all those markers. Anyone know of a way to complete this in Google maps?

Edit: failed to say that I'm using MS-SQL and ASP.NET and I'm pulling dozen to a couple hundred markers and plotting them; not just two (start to finish).

Thanks
Jim

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate distance between two points in google maps V3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502590/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-google-maps-v3)

Comment: See answer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787468/need-to-show-places-on-map-from-database-based-on-longitude-and-latitude/13788462#13788462) Using PDO instead of deprecated mysql_ functions

Comment: Sorry I failed to say that I'm using MS-SQL and ASP.NET.

Comment: To get the total path, sum the distance between all the points...